# req.body empty on posts

Tags: node.js, express, postman

All of a sudden this has been happening to all my projects.

Whenever I make a post in nodejs using express and body-parser `req.body` is an empty object.

```
var express    = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(2000);

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body) // populated!
  res.send(200, req.body);
});
```

Via ajax and postman it's always empty.

However via curl

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:2000/
```

it works as intended.

I tried manually setting `Content-type :  application/json` in the former but I then always get `400 bad request`

This has been driving me crazy.

I thought it was that something updated in body-parser but I downgraded and it didn't help.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So you tried explicitly setting the `Content-Type` in postman? If not, you might try that, as I've had issues before with postman not sending a `Content-Type`.

Comment: yes I did. that is when I recieved 400: invalid json

Comment: @mscdex - thanks i did not set content-tupe in postman and was getting crazy :)

Comment: For those people who are coming here because they wish to send/upload **files** from their APIs and thus have to use form-data. You need something to handle the form data: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer is pretty popular package.

Comment: No matter what, postman doesn't deal with integers and float values very well. If you have integer or float values, ensure to double quote everything, both keys and values

Comment: Once change your content type to sth else and then again change it to json. this solved my problem

Comment: The real answer if you've done everything right - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802608/4010017

Comment: what @kaushalpranav linked to fixed it for me!

Comment: If anyone here is trying to set a content security policy (csp) reporting uri, the content type is often not application/javascript. See this answer for options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64436936/content-security-policy-report-empty-object-in-express

Answer (score 408, accepted):

In Postman of the 3 options available for content type select "X-www-form-urlencoded" and it should work.

Also to get rid of error message replace:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

With:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

See https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

The 'body-parser' middleware only handles JSON and urlencoded data, not multipart

As @SujeetAgrahari mentioned, body-parser is now inbuilt with express.js.

Use `app.use(express.json());` to implement it in recent versions for JSON bodies. For URL encoded bodies (the kind produced by HTTP form POSTs) use `app.use(express.urlencoded());`

Comment: That worked for postman, I'm not sure why it works with ajax as I didn't change anything.

Comment: For some reason http posts via Angular did not need to be URL encoded, but ajax calls did. Anyone know why?

Comment: This worked for me, why wasn't it working with raw encoded though?

Comment: now body-parser is inbuilt with express.js just use `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: I had the same problem. I made sure that I configured express correctly and the problem still occurred. The mistake was that  I set the `Content-Type` in postman before making any requests and the problem was solved when I restarted postman.

Comment: for some reason, a request from another service to my app (a webhook) is parsed correctly when I use `app.use(express.urlencoded());`, but not with `app.use(express.json());` (`request.body` is `{}`, an empty object). If anybody has an idea why, please share.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Make it an answer please. I also don't understand how express doesn't handle such basic by itself.

Comment: It is worth noting that ```app.use(express.json());``` needs to be placed before ```app.get```/```app.post``` to work.

Answer (score 314):

With Postman, to test HTTP post actions with a raw JSON data payload, select the `raw` option and set the following header parameters:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Also, be sure to wrap any strings used as keys/values in your JSON payload in double quotes.

The [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) package will parse multi-line raw JSON payloads just fine.

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

Tested in Chrome v37 and v41 with the Postman v0.8.4.13 extension ([`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) v1.12.2 and [`express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) v4.12.3) with the setup below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// configure the app to use bodyParser()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// ... Your routes and methods here
```

[image: Postman raw json payload]

Comment: Wrapping any strings used as key/values in double quotes... Easy to miss but a total deal breaker otherwise! Thank you.

Comment: When use `form-data` in Postman to post the data, I always get the `{}` in the req.body. Should I set the  `Content-Type` option?

Answer (score 102):

I discovered, that it works when sending with content type

> "application/json"

in combination with server-side
`app.use(express.json())`
(As @marcelocra pointed out, the 2022 version would use)

(old version for reference)
`app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Now I can send via

```
var data = {name:"John"}
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", theUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlHttp.send(data);
```

and the result is available in `request.body.name` on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I really think this is the cleanest, although not the simplest solution, as you should send the correct content type anyways. I think.

Comment: In my case I had to change it to `xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: What is bodyParser, where does it come from ?

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier it is imported right after express.js in the original question. So an external library, basically.

Comment: Per the other answers, seems like the most up-to-date way is using `express.json()` instead of `bodyParser.json()`.

Comment: Thanks mate, just did the edit. If you find more ways to improve the question or anser, please share!

Comment: Make sure `app.use(express.json())` is executed before your HTTP method declarations/mappings

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you!

Comment: @Fred You are very welcome. I call it the SO-feeling :-) Enjoy your cool job! ;-)

Answer (score 81):

I made a really dumb mistake and forgot to define `name` attributes for inputs in my html file.

So instead of

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
```

I have this.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
```

Now `request.body` is populated like this: `{ password: 'hhiiii' }`

Comment: This was my issue, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 24):

You have to check whether the body-parser middleware is set properly to the type of request(json, urlencoded).

If you have set,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

then in postman you have to send the data as raw.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9IdQ.png postman screenshot

If you have set,

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

then 'x-www-form-urlencoded' option should be selected.

Comment: what about having both them? (bodyParser.urlencoded and bodyParser.json())... which one can I use in postman?

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this problem today, and what fixed it was to **remove the content-type header** in Postman! Very strange. Adding it here in case it helps someone.

I was following the BeerLocker tutorial here: http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/29/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-passport/

Comment: i had the same issue.
having the header "unchecked" (and greyed out) was not enough, i had to completely remove it. even though the "</>" source button shows that i was not sending that header with the Content-Type being in the unchecked state, it still needed to be completely removed.

Comment: I can't figure out how to remove the default headers in the postman chrome extension... are you using the app maybe?

Comment: Oh, I installed the app and it works much better than the extension. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 22):

If you are doing with the postman, Please confirm these stuff when you are requesting API

[image]

Comment: this was the case for me. thank you.

Answer (score 20):

For express 4.16+, no need to install body-parser, use the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/your/path', (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Solved it for me. Using it to get body of PUT request. `body-parser` returned empty json body

Answer (score 18):

Express 4.17.1

Server middleware example like this without `bodyParser`;

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

If you're GET requesting header should be like this;

```json
{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

If you're POST requesting header should be like this;

```json
{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

I'am using on client side simple functions like this;

```js
async function _GET(api) {
    return await (await fetch(api, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Accept': '*',
        },
    })).json();
};

async function _POST (api, payload) {
    return await (await fetch(api, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Accept': '*/*',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams(payload),
    })).json();
};
```

Comment: None of this is necessary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379697/1814970).

Comment: This showed me I could use both app.use lines together

Answer (score 15):

My problem was I was creating the route first

```
// ...
router.get('/post/data', myController.postHandler);
// ...
```

and registering the middleware ***after*** the route

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//etc
```

due to app structure & copy and pasting the project together from examples.

Once I fixed the order to register middleware before the route, it all worked.

Answer (score 10):

In postman, even after following the accepted answer, I was getting an empty request body. The issue turned out to be not passing a header called

```
Content-Length : <calculated when request is sent>
```

This header was present by default (along with 5 others) which I have disabled. Enable this and you'll receive the request body.

Comment: Also, make sure the tool you are using for sending the requests sends the proper headers in general. In my case, I used a different tool with the exact same request and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

The error source is not defining the specific header type when the postman request is made. I simply solved it by either adding

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Or explicitly defining the raw data type as JSON in postman while making the request also solves the problem.

Comment: had to check `Content-Lenght` while making Postman request. Otherwise, it would throw an error.

Comment: @ghimirehillson 's solution solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Even when i was learning node.js for the first time where i started learning it over web-app, i was having all these things done in well manner in my form, still i was not able to receive values in post request. After long debugging, i came to know that in the form i have provided `enctype="multipart/form-data"` due to which i was not able to get values. I simply removed it and it worked for me.

Comment: yes, this also worked to get the form body **but** then caused another problem with my form - basically the file could not be uploaded as this requires `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: btw, just to add to my above comment, I managed to get this working with `multer` - see documentation on https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 4):

I solved this using `multer` as suggested above, but they missed giving a full working example, on how to do this. Basically this can happen when you have a form group with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Here's the HTML for the form I had:

```
<form action="/stats" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of speakers" name="nspeakers">
    <input type="submit" value="Get me the stats!" class="btn btn-default">            
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's how to use `multer` to get the values and names of this form with `Express.js` and `node.js`:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: './public/data/uploads/' })
app.post('/stats', upload.single('uploaded_file'), function (req, res) {
   // req.file is the name of your file in the form above, here 'uploaded_file'
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
   console.log(req.file, req.body)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure ["key" : "type", "value" : "json"] & ["key":"Content-Type", "value":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"] is in your postman request headers

Answer (score 3):

It seems if you do not use any encType (default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) then you do get text input fields but you wouldn't get file.

If you have a form where you want to post text input and file then use `multipart/form-data` encoding type and in addition to that use `multer` middleware. Multer will parse the request object and prepare `req.file` for you and all other inputs fields will be available through `req.body`.

Comment: thanks - `multer` was indeed the solution to my problem. It would be good if you could add an example on how to use this as part of your answer

Answer (score 3):

I believe this can solve `app.use(express.json());`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by changing the enctype of my form on the front-end:

- It was ⛔️ `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`
- I changed it for ✅ `<form enctype="application/json">`

It was a relief to see the data eventually pop into the console ^^

Comment: This was my problem, ever since I upgraded mongoose from v6 to v7 and using the latest nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem happened to me, I simply mixed the order of the callback params. Make sure your are setting up the callback functions in the correct order. At least for anyone having the same problem.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){});
```

Comment: I solved my problems removing any express.json() express.urlencode() or bady-parse and writing so
app.post('/path',function(req,res){
   data=""
   // we can access HTTP headers
   req.on('data', chunk => {
      data+=chunk
   })
   req.on('end', () => {
      console.log(data)
      js=JSON.parse(data)
   })
})

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have the name in my Input ... my request was empty... glad that is finished and I can keep coding. Thanks everyone!

Answer I used by Jason Kim:

So instead of

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
```

I have this

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not do `JSON.stringify(data)` while sending through AJAX like below.

This is NOT correct code:

```
function callAjax(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(d) {
            alert("successs "+ JSON.stringify(d));
        }
    });
}
```

The correct code is:

```
function callAjax(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(d) {
            alert("successs "+ JSON.stringify(d));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: a key thing to note here is that in type, make sure you capitalize "POST". I've seen instances where just using "post" has lead to blank req.body.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few minutes ago, I tried everything possible in the above answers but any of them worked.

The only thing I did, was upgrade Node JS version, I didn't know that upgrading could affect in something, but it did.

I have installed Node JS version `10.15.0` (latest version), I returned to `8.11.3` and everything is now working. Maybe `body-parser` module should take a fix on this.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was creating the route first 
    `require("./routes/routes")(app);`
I shifted it to the end of the code before 
    `app.listen`
and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick input - I had the same problem(Testing my private api with insomnia) and when I added the Content-Type: application/json, it instantly worked. What was confusing me was that I had done everything pretty much the same way for the GET and POST requests, but PUT did not seem to work. I really really hope this helps get someone out of the rabbit hole of debugging!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have removed the enctype attribute at the form tag when the form is not containing any file upload input

```
enctype='multipart/form-data
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTML tag name attribute

```html
<input name="fname">
```

body-parser use tag name attribute to identify tag's.

Comment: Thanks, you have helped a backender from a two days html black hole

Answer (score 1):

I simply solved the issue removing any .json() or .urlencode() for app.use() both for express and body-parser because they gave me some problems. I wrote my code recreating streaming with this simply solution

```
app.post('/mypath',function(req,res){
   data=""
   // we can access HTTP headers
   req.on('data', chunk => {
      data+=chunk
   })
   req.on('end', () => {
      console.log(data)
      // here do what you want with data
      // Eg: js=JSON.parse(data)
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using restify instead of express and ran into the same problem. The solution was to do:

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());` in your code to

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
```

and in postman, in header change `Content-Type` value from 
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`

Ta:-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your great answers! 
Spent quite some time searching for a solution, and on my side I was making an elementary mistake: I was calling `bodyParser.json()` from within the function :

```js
app.use(['/password'], async (req, res, next) => {
  bodyParser.json()
  /.../
  next()
})
```

I just needed to do `app.use(['/password'], bodyParser.json())` and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Fetch API to send the POST request and in the body, I was sending an object instead of a string.

Mistake -> `{ body: { email: 'value' } }`

I corrected by stringifying the body -> `{ body: JSON.stringify({ email: 'value' }) }`