# req.body of post router contains new line and colon?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I would like to know how to extract the post data from req.body.

My post data is

```
{
 name:'asdf',
 completed: false,
 note: 'asdf'
}
```

When I am trying to console it using JSON.stringify , I am getting req.body as

```
{"{\n name:'asdf',completed:false,note:'asdf'}":""}
```

I noticed that new line and colon are getting added to the req.body object. So when I am trying to filter req.body.name its returning me undefined.

I have used `app.use(bodyParser.json());`but still I am not getting the actual result

Hence I would like to know the following:
1. How to filter the post object?
2. Why new lines and colon are getting added to req.body object?

Comment: Are you setting the header data-type of the POST to JSON?

Comment: I am using advance rest client for sending the request, 
I have set Content-Type = application/json 
and I am passing data as 
{'name':'asdf',
'completed':false,
'note':'asdf'}

Comment: previously by mistake , I set content-type as application/x-www-form-url encoded. Now when I set it to application/json , I am getting response as bad request. What am I missing?

Comment: can you stringify the data before you post it?

Comment: I tried it by stringifying as "{'name':'asdf',
'completed':false,
'note':'asdf'}" , but still I am getting as bad request

Comment: please show me your code..

Comment: @gopinathshiva set the content type back to x-www-form-url encoded, then send the data stringified. On the server, parse it.

Comment: I dont feel passing data as stringified would be a correct solution. Anyway I found answer myself. Appreciate your help dude. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself by following
[req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

As I am testing in rest-client, The mistakes I did are,

1. I initially made content-type:www-form-urlencoded. Then later I made it as application/json
2. I didnt use quotes for key in key-value pair. so you need to pass data in raw section as

   {"name":"asdf",
   "completed":false,
   "note":"asdf"}

Note: Though www-form-urlencoded also work, when you are passing data in form section as

```
name      asdf
completed false
note      asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

All the parsers accept a type option which allows you to change the Content-Type that the middleware will parse.

```
// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON 
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer 
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }))

// parse an HTML body into a string 
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }))
```