# Express set app.use middleware in every file?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I've created a very basic express js application. After setting routes and other things I did `app.use('/api/', require('./api/api.js'));`

api.js looks something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res){
      res.end(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using Postman chrome extension to post to this route. The response is empty `{}`.

The question is: as long as I have in my `app.js` `body-parser` middleware set do I need to set it again in `api.js` ? If not why I have an empty response ?

In `app.js` body-parser is set like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
}));
```

Comment: what did you put in the POST body with postman?

Comment: `author`, `content` and `msg`. All text. form-data.

Comment: When I do `var express = require('express');` in my `api.js` file the express variable has all things set from `app.js`, right ?

Comment: How are you creating 'app' ? can you post both your app.js and api.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

var api = require('./api');
app.use('/api', api);


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send((req.body);
});

module.exports = router
```

Then, in your PostMan request, something like:

[image]

Comment: if I do something like this `res.send("something");` I can see the response in postman. The problem is with the body-parser. `"express": "^4.12.3"`, `"body-parser": "^1.12.2"`

Comment: hmm.. i suspect it's something to do with your request in Postman - could you try and post a screenshot to your main question?

Comment: which version of express are you using?

Comment: @George02 see my edit - notice var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 - and then see screnshot of my PostMan request. be sure to set content type to application/json

Comment: I took your example, I did `npm install express body-parser --save` and it won't work. I tested with another REST client(chrome extension). The data that I send to server need to be in the header or in the `payload` ?

Comment: the response is empty `{}` `req.body` is not filled by body-parser and I don't know why.

Comment: Doing what @sirthud says here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts work. Posting in raw format.

Answer (score 0):

You used `/api/` in `app.use('/api/', require('./api/api.js'));` to use the route and in route you used `router.post('/', ...`. If you remove the trailing forward slash in `/api/` it might work.