# POST not working on Node.JS & Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get user input from a html form but can't retrieve the data.
This is the HTML code:

```
<form action="/login" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

And here is the Node.JS code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

When I input data on the form, the post request returns {}. However, using Postman it works just fine...

Comment: Use `name` instead of `id` in your input elements

Comment: @choz already did, still not working.

Comment: @Ivan Which version of `Express` you're using out there?

Comment: @DavidR I'm using version 4.2.0

Comment: Did you install `body-parser` package by this command `npm install body-parser` ?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna yes I did

Comment: @Ivan Can you try placing `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` below `app.use(bodyParser.json());` ?

Comment: @DavidR That fixed it! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ivan Glad it has fixed your issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [req.body empty on posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `bodyParser.urlencoded` method to get it working.

Add the below snippet below your `app.use(bodyParser.json());' statement.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
     extended: true
}));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

***After Express 4.16.0+***

No need for body-parser package.

```
import express, { urlencoded } from 'express';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```