# Why is req.body empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, post, body-parser

**Server:**

```
//Body Parser
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

**Client:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="../users/editProfile" class="uploadForm">
```

For some reason, `req.body` is always empty when I submit the form. It was working perfectly fine before and to my knowledge the only thing I added where 9 more inputs for a total of 15.

What could have caused this ?

I already checked this: [req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

None of the answers seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've loaded body parsers that can support:

- URL encoding
- JSON encoding

Your form is configured to use `multipart/form-data`, which is neither of those.

Use the [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) parser for `multipart/form-data` bodies.

Comment: Now I understand what just happened... I had indeed removed multer.