# Trying to make Supertest send a body to https post?

Tags: node.js, express, https, supertest

I am new and fail to make supertest work for me. I am wondering:

- Why is the body undefined?
- Is there a trick from the command line to show and inspect objects in the console?
- Why doesn't the test logs "hello"?

```js
 "use strict";
 
 const request = require('supertest');
 const express = require('express');
 const https = require('https');
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path');
 const certPath = path.resolve(path.resolve(), './certs');
 
 const app = express();
 
 //This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
 const options = {
  key : fs.readFileSync(certPath+'/server-key.pem'),
  cert : fs.readFileSync(certPath+'/server-crt.pem'),
  ca : fs.readFileSync(certPath+'/ca-crt.pem')
 };
 
 // service
 app.post('/failService', function(req, res) {
  console.log('failService: '+req.body); // failService: undefined
  res.send('hello');
 });
 
 describe('trial not working', function() {
   it('responds with json', function(done) {
    request(app)
       .post('/failService')
       .send({name: 'john'})
       .set('Accept', /json/)
       .expect(200)
       .end(function(err, res) {
         if (err) return done(err);
         console.log('response: '+res.body); // response: [object Object]
         done();
       });
   });
 });
```

.... shows

$ mocha supertest.js

```
  trial not working
failService: undefined
response: [object Object]
    √ responds with json (125ms)


  1 passing (171ms)
```

Please note that the certificates (not included) are self signed.

Answer (score 0):

When isolating my code above I missed the options. As a result it does not use SSL. Sorry for that.

I fell back to starting the server and the use of a client in my test case. For that I had to fix:

1. [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)
2. [The actual problem of this post by using a body parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the self signed certificate.

i also faced similar issue there are two possible solutions

1. Create http server instead of https server for test environment
2. Replace `supertest` with `superrequest` npm package and set strictSsl as false.