# Request body is empty when posting form-data

Tags: node.js, express, client, backend, body-parser

I'm using a simple post request to my backend for a form data and for some reason the body is alwayes empty.
I'm trying to isolate this so i changed the content type to application json and changed the data to json and only this way i can send data.

**Client side:**

```
submitForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("gggg");
        const data = new FormData(event.target);

         axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user-form-post",data).then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
        });
```

**Server side:**

```
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.post('/user-form-post', (req,res) =>{

    console.log("dfdf");
    console.log(req.body); // alwayes print empty dict {}
    res.end();

})
```

This is not working because it expects jsons(expected behavior):

```
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

Same behavior with Postman.

Comment: for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded, aren't you supposed to use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` ?

Comment: Tried this as well. Not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts this may help you

Comment: Already looked at this...Nothing helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to parse your form data from express side. For this you will have to use multer or multiparty. Try something like this. refer the documentation as well

```
const multiparty = require('multiparty');

app.post('/user-form-post', (req,res) =>{

   let form = new multiparty.Form();

   form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(name) {
           console.log('got field named ' + name);
       });
   });
})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more why req.body is empty?

Comment: @KaramJaber This is because you are sending form data from the front-end and express can not parse form data. For that you will have to use some kind of a middlewares which is capable of parsing form data. The most famous middleware are multer  and multiparty.

Comment: @TRomesh Why can't Express handle such a common use case? Is a library 100% necessary?

Answer (score 2):

when it comes to my issue,
i have this front end

```
 const form = new FormData();
      form.email = this.email;
      form.password = this.password;
      console.log("onSubmit -> form", form);

axios.post("http://localhost:3000/register",  form )
```

```
onSubmit -> form FormData {email: "admin@gmail.com", password: "123"}
```

but the req.body in backend is empty, and i figured it out that the form in axios.post still need 1 more bracket {} even it's a object.  like this

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/register", { form })
```

After that backend got body like this

```
req.body = { form: { email: 'admin@gmail.com', password: '123' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

A problem with request body when you post data is `data type` .

I have recently a problem with `Postman` .
You should post data with type `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `raw`->JSON to fix the problem.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
app.use( bodyParser.json() );  // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

Please, also use given below line code but first install multer and write the code in top of your application:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue , spent 2 days . Here are the solutions i found :

1. my request payload had JSON.stringify() , it will make body as {} empty object . when i removed JSON.stringify() and sent request it worked .
2. Content type should be multipart-form :boundary -----
3. Now if i externally set it to multipart-form , boundary thing was missing.
   for few people it worked when you set content-type as false / undefined , boundary thing got added up,but not for me .
4. Even though i followed all steps and sending FormData as payload, payload was request payload object in network tab and was not FormData object , my request failed with 500 .
5. i tried the below code , its react + typescript (make necessary  changes to avoid syntax errors)

```js
import QueryString from 'qs';
import { ApiParams } from './xyzfile';
import { ApiHandlerRawType } from './types/xyzfile';



const setDefaultOptions = ({
  method = '',
  url = '',
  params = {},
  data = {},
  signal = null,
  headers = new Headers(),
  ...options
} = {}) => ({
  method,
  url,
  params,
  signal,
  headers,
  data,
  ...options
});

const setData = ({ method, data, ...options }: ApiHandlerRawType) => {
  const option = options;
  if (method !== 'GET' && option.isStreamData) {
    option.body = data;
  }
  return {
    method,
    ...option
  };
};

const addRequestHeaders = ({ headers = new Headers(), ...options }) => {
  const { existingHeaders }: ApiHandlerRawType = options;
  if (existingHeaders) {
    Object.entries(existingHeaders).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key !== 'Content-Type') headers.set(key, value);
    });
  }
  return {
    headers,
    ...options
  };
};

export const ApiHandlerRaw = ({
  url,
  ...originalOptions
}: ApiHandlerRawType): Promise<Response> => {
  const options = setData(
    addRequestHeaders(setDefaultOptions(originalOptions))
  );
  return fetch(url || '', options)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
      return Promise.resolve(response);
    })
    .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
};

export const FileUploadApiHandler = async ({
  headers,
  ...options
}: ApiHandlerRawType): Promise<Response | Blob> => {
  const response = await ApiHandlerRaw({
    headers,
    isStreamData: true,
    ...options
  });
  return response;
};

    export const fileApiService = ({
      url,
      method,
      qsObject,
      headers,
      reqObjectAsStreamData
    }: ApiParams): Promise<Response> => {
      const qs = QueryString.stringify(qsObject, { addQueryPrefix: true });
      const urlPath = `${url}${qs}`;
      const data = reqObjectAsStreamData;
      const existingHeaders = headers;
      return FileUploadApiHandler({
        url: urlPath,
        method,
        data,
        existingHeaders
      }) as Promise<Response>;
    };
```

send the required variables  from fileApiService . existingHeaders would be your app headers , eg : token / ids ... etc . data in fileApiService is the body .

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced the same issue in the published code.

But I have fixed this issue by using the below code highlighted in the attached image :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fG4EB.png)

There is no use of **"Content-Type"** to fix this issue.

Hope you fix your issue by using the above code snippets.

Comment: It recommended that users provide code snippets in the answer itself and not links to external sources. The code in the image can be added to the answer within a code snippet.