# Target server not recieving the request body in http-proxy?

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I am trying to introduce gateway for my micro services. I got stuck in post method. Target server not receiving the request body. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Can any one help me out. Here is the code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
const server1 = 'http://localhost:4000',
        server2 = 'http://localhost:4001';

apiProxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req) => {
        console.log(' in proxy req ...');
        if (req.body) {
                const bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
                // incase if content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded -> we need to change to application/json
                proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                proxyReq.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(bodyData));
                // stream the content
                proxyReq.write(bodyData);
                apiProxy.web(req,res, {target: server2});
        }
});

app.all('/service1/*', (req,res) => {
        console.log("redirecting to server1 ...");
        apiProxy.web(req,res, {target: server1});
})

app.all('/service2/*', (req,res) => {
        console.log(" req, body : ", req.body);
        apiProxy.web(req,res, {target: server2});
})

apiProxy.on('error', (err,req,res) => {
        console.log('got an error : ',err)
});

apiProxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes,req,res) => {
        console.log(' got a response from the server ..');
        return proxyRes;
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(' proxy running on 3000'));
```

By using the body parser i am able to print request body but not getting the request body on the target server.

```
const app = express();
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
const server1 = 'http://localhost:4000',
        server2 = 'http://localhost:4001';

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.all('/service1/*', (req,res) => {
        console.log("redirecting to server1 ...");
        apiProxy.web(req,res, {target: server1});
})

app.all('/service2/*', (req,res) => {
        console.log(" req, body : ", req.body);
        apiProxy.web(req,res, {target: server2});
})

apiProxy.on('error', (err,req,res) => {
        console.log('got an error : ',err)
});

apiProxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes,req,res) => {
        console.log(' got a response from the server ..');
        return proxyRes;
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(' proxy running on 3000'));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Comment: no. i am getting undefined.

Comment: Hi @Pulipati, I'm having almost exactly the same problem, did you ever solve this issue and if so would you mind sharing your solution? The suggestion by Bernard also did not help me.

Comment: If you tried using jsonParser in your proxy server, make sure you use it before any routing. It means use it right after you create express app.