# How to get the post request params in express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

The following is the code for posting a product using an angular service.
Here I'm passing the product as the body

```
  addProduct(product): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Observable<any>>(
      `http://localhost:4401/api/products`,
      {
        product,
      }
    );
  }
```

But when I try to access it inside my express server I am getting an undefined.

```
app.post("/api/products", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req :", req.body);
});
```

Other verbs like `GET`, `DELETE` is working fine.

Also the following is also working fine:

```
app.get("/api/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const responseData = await db.get(req.query.id);

    res.json({ product: responseData  });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

But the params inside the `POST` verbe is not getting received inside the express server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [req.body empty on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)

Comment: Actually body parser is deprecated. I use multer. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to parse json-payloads you need an appropriate parser set up. You can use express's built-in parser to do that:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/api/products", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req :", req.body);
});
```

Comment: Happy to help, please don't forget to upvote/accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side.