# How to transfer files to fetch server

Tags: node.js, react-native, express

I am sending the following post request to the server

```
async function onPressLogin (state) {
  const data = {username:state.email,password:state.password}
  console.log('data at Json: ',JSON.stringify(data))
  try {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login",{
      mode: "no-cors",
      method:"POST",
      body:JSON.stringify(data),
      headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    })
    let result = await response.json()
    console.log('Result: ',result)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Catch:',e.message)      
  }
}
```

But on the server `request.body` is `{}` What can be the issue here?

Comment: Are you using express on node server ??

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts