# req.body results empty with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a POST request with **Express**, but req.body result to be **empty** {}.
I've tried with Postman, and it works. I noticed that the input fields after submit are correct so I can't figure out what the problem is. Attached you can find the code I've written for the POST request. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
<form class="sign-up_form needs-validation" id="formwork" encType="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost:3000/new_work" method="post" novalidate>
                <div class="div_header">
              
                    <header class="head-form">
                        <h2 class="sign-up_text">Inserisci il tuo workshop</h2>
                       
                        <p>Fatti conoscere attraverso la nostra accademia!</p>
                    </header>
                 
                </div>
               
                <div class="con-signup">
                    <br>
                    <div class="field_set1_sign-up">
                        
                        <span class="input-item">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                     
                        <input class="form-input" id="nomework" name="nomework" type="text" placeholder="Nome workshop" required>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                      
                        <span class="input-item">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                       
                        <input class="form-input" id="tipologia" name="tipologia" type="text" placeholder="Tipologia workshop" list="tip" required>
                        <datalist id="tip">
                            <option>Fotografia</option>
                            <option>Videomaker</option>
                            <option>Postproduzione</option>
                        </datalist>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Devi definire la categoria del tuo workshop.
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                       
                        <span class="input-item">
                            <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                        
                        <input class="form-input" id="datawork" name="datawork" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Data e ora workshop" required>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-sign">
                    <button class="sign-up-btn" id="submit">Inserisci workshop</button>
                </div>
            </form>

    app.post('/new_work', (req, res) => {
console.log("BODY: ",req.body); // empty body {}
const workshop = {
    nome : req.body.nomework,
    nomeutente : req.session.passport.user.username,
    nomefotografo : req.session.passport.user.name,
    cognomefotografo : req.session.passport.user.surname,
    tipologia : req.body.tipologia,
    data : req.body.datawork
};

vpa.insertWorkshop(workshop)
    .then((result) => res.redirect("workshop.html"))
    .catch((err) => res.status(503).json({ error: 'Errore db durante la registrazione del workshop'}));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this middleware before your routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // <---
```

There are a lot more detailed explained answers here on StackOverflow addressed to this question. Please research them first. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've already tried to add the lines without success. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you restarted your express server after your try? If you are using `nodemon`, you don't need to do that tho.

Comment: Yes, but the error persist. If can help, I've already created a working registration form. Do you noticed any issues in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

// other code below...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried to add these lines and the error persist.