# How To Solve Eror Cast to number failed for value "undefined" (type undefined) at path "jumlah"' in javascript using fetch

Tags: javascript, request, fetch

```
const someData = {jumlah: 12}

const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/data/nama/FNQN'

const putMethod = {

 method: 'PUT', // Method itself

 headers: {

  'Content-type': 'application/json' // Indicates the content 

 },

 body: JSON.stringify(someData) // We send data in JSON format

}

// make the HTTP put request using fetch api

fetch(url, putMethod)

.then(response => response.json())

.then(data => console.log(data)) // Manipulate the data retrieved back, if we want to do something with it

.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I ran this script and got error
Cast to number failed for value "undefined" (type undefined) at path "jumlah"'

I used fetch and request its till same

I tried to put data in localhost and I got error

its side code

```
const updateDatasName = asyncHandler(async (req,res) => {
    const datas = await Datas.findOne({ namaplayer: { $eq: req.params.namaplayer } })
    if(!datas){
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('Data Kosong')
    }
    
    if(!req.body.dec){
        await Datas.findOneAndUpdate({namaplayer: req.params.namaplayer},{ $inc: { jumlah: req.body.jumlah} })
        const datas = await Datas.findOne({ namaplayer: { $eq: req.params.namaplayer }})
        res.status(200).json(datas)
    }else{
        await Datas.findOneAndUpdate({namaplayer: req.params.namaplayer},{ $inc: { jumlah: -req.body.jumlah} })
        const datas = await Datas.findOne({ namaplayer: { $eq: req.params.namaplayer }})
        res.status(200).json(datas)
    }
})
```

Comment: How your server side works? Is server side use `req.body.jumlah`?

Comment: yes, use ```req.body.jumlah```

Comment: Where did those error msg show? Server or client? Provide server side code for more info plz.

Comment: done add the side code

Comment: Maybe `req.body.jumlah` is `'12'` not `12`, try `parseInt(req.body.jumlah)`

Comment: in the server code right?

Comment: i got eror "Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path jumlah

Comment: req.body is undefined, install body-parser to resolve it.

Comment: i already install it, what next

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543847/req-body-empty-on-posts)